# facesMessage and ice:Messages

Tags: java, icefaces

Quick question. Is it possible to associate a facesMessage with a particular ice:Messages tag?

i.e. I create

```
facesMessage.add("Error message one");
facesMessage.add("Error message two");
```

And in my page I have

```
<ice:messages style="float:center;color: #FF0000" id="errorMessageOne"/>
<ice:messages style="float:center;color: #FF0000" id="errorMessageTwo"/>
```

So I want to kick off "Error message one" where the message id="errorMessageOne" and kick off "Error message two" where message id=errorMessageTwo.

Any tips on this?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Seam?
If so you can do it very easily with seam.

Look [here][1]

[1]: http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.0.1.CR1/api/org/jboss/seam/faces/FacesMessages.html#addToControl(java.lang.String, javax.faces.application.FacesMessage)